# Mocking api request with jest and react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing api request call using jest and react testing library , here is my codes.

Live demo [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mocking-api-request-zu2jx?file=/src/__test__/Home.test.js)

utils/api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

export default instance;

export async function get(url, params) {
  const response = await instance({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    params: params,
  });
  return response;
}
```

**mock**/api.js

```
    const mockResponse = {
      data: {
        attributes: {
          first_name: "Jeff",
          last_name: "Bezo's",
        },
      },
    };

export default {
  get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockResponse),
};
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Home() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/users/self");
      console.log("data response..", response.data);
      setUser(response.data.attributes.first_name);
    } catch (error) {}

  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

    return <div data-testid="user-info" > Welcome {user}</div>;
}

export default Home;
```

Home.test.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { render, cleanup, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import Home from "../../editor/Home";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../app/store";
import Loader from "../../components/Loader/Loader";

const MockHomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Home />
      </Suspense>
    </Provider>
  );
};

    describe("Home component", () => {
      it("should return a user name", async () => {
        render(<MockHomeComponent />);
        const userDivElement = await screen.findByTestId(`user-info`);
        expect(userDivElement).toBeInTheDocument();
        screen.debug();
      });
    
      afterAll(cleanup);
    });
```

**Problem:**

When I run `npm run test` test is passed but in the `screen.debug()` results I dont see the user name returned as expected I just see `Welcome`. but it should be `welcome Jeff`.

What am I doing wrong here? any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Use [`act`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act) and then follow [this recipe](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching).

Comment: While i'm here, there's no reason to have a MockHomeComponent at all as it's not lazy and doesn't use redux.

Comment: @Adam lazy and suspemse is being used in my app.js

Comment: @Adam your wrong about act , Kent C says its wrong check it here https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library

Comment: The quote from that blog is: `Advice: Learn when act is necessary and don't wrap things in act unnecessarily.` Is it necessary, or unnecessary in this case? Please don't tell me I'm wrong until you've tried it. The documentation from [react's own website](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching) tells you how to do it.

Comment: @Adam okay my bad, I wraped up with act but still the screen debug results still the same just welcome no name returned

Comment: Did you `async/await` the `act` (as in the react documentation)? If so, post your updated code.

Comment: @Adam https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3e3B.png

Comment: EDITED: Too harsh [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching) says you need to render it into a `container`

Comment: @Adam here is live demo in codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/mocking-api-request-zu2jx?file=/src/__test__/Home.test.js

Comment: The easiest way i found is using ```moxios```.

Comment: @cybercoder did you test with live demo?

Comment: @TheDeadMan I sent you a sample in answer. I'll delete it after you read that.

Comment: @Adam they're using `@testing-library/react` which wraps its queries in `act` already, it's rare you need to use it for the library.
They're getting `act` warnings for their test because OP is checking for existence of `data-testid`, when that exists before API request completes (making it a false positive), and a state update is happening during the assertion.

Comment: Thank you @JulianFlynn!